# html / javascript - desaturate / grayscale image rollovers without creating an image duplicate or sprite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rollover

I want to do a grayscale to color image rollover on my images, but I don't want to use a technique that requires creating a duplicate of the image, and I want to avoid sprites. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is possible using canvas and some JS.
here is an working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/csbaf/

http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html (you will need to preload the images...)

PS: there is even a fallback for IE

Comment: ah - nice! How do you resaturate though?

Comment: i would just cover the original image with the desaturated version.